# I want to remove the overlaps from a multishape design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

[image]

I want to remove the selected part from the design. I have used rotate tool to make the copies and divided them by the Pathfinder panel/Divide. I have ungrouped the result.

Now I want to remove the selected path and leave the original green clean surface. By pressing "delete" I get a white hole. What to do? PLEASE, HELP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you really got the overlap deleted, but probably you want to combine it to one of the slices and not to delete it. So select the overlap-slice and another slice. In the Patfinder panel press Unite.

You can unite all copies if you want only one path.

Also Pathfinder/Merge does the trick somehow. It 
- kills the overlaps, but do not leave holes
- removes the visible stroke and group all.

It's still possible to ungroup the slices and to give strokes to them.

Check also, if Object > Arrange > Bring to front for some parts just after the copying is enough. The blue place indicators of the paths are not visible if not wanted.

Comment: But I have seen a video on youtube in which upper overlapped surfaces are removed. I am sending the link:  https://youtu.be/8Z9V6OrlkfM

Comment: @NILESH At 2:03 the videoman uses Pathfinder panel's Subtract. Later he didvides the bunch and starts to kill the unwanted slices. Occasionally he kills also something that has nothing else behind, but the background He cancels that kill by ctrl+Z. There are more than 2 shapes overlapping at some places. That produces overlapping slices, too.

Comment: So how to kill unwanted slices.

Comment: @nilesh unite them with wanted slices. No holes will pop up.